# Sending message from content script to react app not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I'm sending messages from chrome extension content script to my react app using window post message:

```
window.postMessage({ type: "Action", action: action }, "*");
```

And I'm receiving it this way :

```
window.addEventListener("message", function(e) {
console.log(e.data.action)
});
```

It's working fine but it only works when I click on my chrome extension icon, If I don't click on it and navigate in the extension components my react app won't recieve any messages.
Is there a way to keep my react app always up whenever the extension is in my browser ?

Comment: Declare your [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) in manifest.json instead of using executeScript.

Comment: @wOxxOm I'm already declaring my content script in my manifest.json

Comment: In that case the problem is somewhere else in your code, which isn't shown in the question. Also make sure you reload the tabs after you reload your extension on chrome://extensions page.

Comment: @wOxxOm the thing is that I'm using a modal window instead of popup, so whenever I open the model window the extension run one more time. For example if I click on the extension icon 3 times, it'll console log e.data.action 3 times.

Comment: Without [MCVE](/help/mcve) we can only guess blindly which isn't productive.